# Why the C recv() function in my self-write dll stocked even broke my Labview program if I didn't keep sending data from server.c via TCP socket

Tags: c, dll, labview

I want to write a simple TCP socket Client dll base on C Language
import to my Labview program.
I defined three functions in my dll as follow:

```
char* DLL_EXPORT TCPSocket(int input); //open socket
void DLL_EXPORT closeSocket(void); //close socket
int DLL_EXPORT pulse(int trig); //waiting incoming signal from server.c and return a value
```

the first two of them worked great,
But the last one always blocks and broke my Labview if it didn't receive anything.
The main function I want is that waiting for a trigger signal from my Server,
So this must exist a waiting time interval, and that is why it caused my Labview to crashed.

```
int DLL_EXPORT pulse(int trig)
{
  int Text;
  int pass = 0, rx;

  send(sock,(char *)&trig,sizeof(trig),0);
  rx = recv(sock,(char *)&Text,64,0);
  while(1)
  {
    if(rx <= 0)
    {
      pass = 0;
      break;
    }
    else if(rx > 0)
    {
      pass = Text;
      break;
    }
    return pass;
  }
  return pass;
}
```

Is it possible to create a dll for Labview just to waiting for an output finished signal and plz don't
crash my LabVIEW?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KayC.jpg)

Comment: So you try to receive 64 Bytes (512bit) into an INT value???

Comment: oh maybe not that large, 4 Bytes may be much enough as a trigger signal.
I'll send such as integer "1" or something else string as a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why LV might crash when calling a DLL. For example a segmentation fault or any other crash inside the DLL.

With `int Text;`, you allocate 4 bytes of memory to store the incoming data, but you allow the `recv()` function to receive up to 64 bytes. If it received more than 4 bytes, it writes data beyond the memory boundary of `Text`, and this can lead to a segmentation fault. Just allow up to 4 bytes (or `sizeof(Text)`) to be read.

By the way: If you receive a single byte like `A` (or `0x41`), it will be placed in the most significant byte of `Text`, so `Text` will be 0x41000000=‭1090519040‬. But only if `Text` were 0 before. You do not initialize it, which means it could contain any random value.

Next, what is `sock`? It is not declared anywhere in your code. (It is, otherwise it would not compile) If `sock` is not initialized correctly, `recv()` might crash.

Finally, the current functionality can be achieved within LabVIEW. Is there any reason for using a DLL?

Comment: Why I need to use DLL is that I found out some utterly strange problem with LabVIEW's
TCP function at first, it always received not correct # of bytes of my data string.
Second, I thought the speed of LabVIEW's build-in TCP vi may not as fast as we expected. But I can still try whether the build-in TCP vi could work or not.
I think I may have some misunderstanding with LabVIEW's vi.

Comment: You can almost certainly do what you want with the LabView TCP Read function. It is quite fast. For performance applications, you probably want to use "Immediate" mode (read all available data and return immediately.)